# Neo4j's Java Algorithm binding does not work with big dataset but Cypher does

Tags: java, algorithm, neo4j

I'm trying to use `findAllPaths` find shortest paths between two random nodes, but the program just stuck there with no output(it works pretty fine when I doing the Unit test with a toy db which is relatively small). The CPU usage is quite low so I do not think it is doing the computing while sticking.

So I try to use the `ExecutionEngine` instead, and that works prefect fine and returns the result in several microseconds. I just curious why the Algorithm API does not work with a big database(8 million nodes and 300 million directed edges)? Or I made some mistake? I barely follow the tutorial on their website http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo.html, all I change is I do not specify any particular relation type in my search.

By the way, My Neo4j version is `1.9.4`.

Here is the code :

```
while(startNode==null){
    startNode = nodeFinder.getSingleNodeByIndex("wikipage", "id", random.nextInt(MAX_TUPLE));
}
while(stopNode==null){
    stopNode = nodeFinder.getSingleNodeByIndex("wikipage", "id", random.nextInt(MAX_TUPLE));
}
```

This part works

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(GraphDataBase.getInstance().getGraphDB());
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("start source=node:wikipage(id=\""+startNode.getId()+"\"), dest=node:wikipage(id=\""+stopNode.getId()+"\") match p=allShortestPaths(source-[r:WIKI_LINK*..8]->dest) return nodes(p);");
```

But this does not

```
PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(Traversal.expanderForAllTypes(Direction.OUTGOING), 8 );
Iterable<Path> paths = finder.findAllPaths( startNode, stopNode );
```